# How to represent missing value in web / React / TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, web, default-value

I can use `null`, `undefined`, or `""` in web to represent ie.e in a login form then no value is set yet. Which is the best approach?

It is so much easier in Swift. There is only `nil` as option for missing value. What to do in web?

I face now with two constrains

1. If I use `null`, I got in Typescript:

```
Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string | number | readonly string[] | undefined'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | number | readonly string[] | undefined'.
```

2. If I set undefined, I got the "controller uncontroller" error.

> A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. More info: https://reactjs.org/link/controlled-components

meaningful code for a login screen:

```
<input
    className={'input-text'}
    value={email}
```

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState<string | null>(null)
```

Shall I use `""`, it is so much against the approach other languages following.

If I good understand React recommend using `""`, right?

https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Answer (score 0):

`null` is a value that is explicitly assigned to a variable to indicate that it has no value or that it should be set to nothing. It is a special value that represents nothing, empty, or non-existent.

`undefined`, on the other hand, is a value that indicates a variable has been declared, but it has not been assigned a value yet. It is also the default value of function parameters that are not provided.